# Windows Mobile 6.5 app doesn't show up in Task manager

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I created my first windows mobile 6.5 app recently and my client tells me the app doesn't appear in the task manager. What could be the possible causes for this problem?

- I checked google, nothing
- I posted on MSDN forums, no answers
- I checked all properties of the main form, i have control box, minimize box, maximize box turned on, the form is never closed...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you [read this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/application-not-visible-task-manager-t3962865.html) and does it help? Essentially: Does the form have a `Caption` text assigned? If not, it will not show up in the task manager.

Comment: This is most probably the problem as the form doesn't have a caption, i don't have the device right now, my boss needs it to discuss with the client but i'll test it ASAP and flag you if you got it

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, it actually does "show" up in the task manager, if it does not have a window title it's a blank entry, but it is there.  You can click on it and end process etc.

Comment: I'm giving you a upvote just for the trouble of answering for nothing a question that was posted almost 3 years ago, cheers!